# Dynamic mapping with sigma.js or other plugin

Tags: jquery, maps, sigma.js

This question is for sigma.js.

I store in mysql a number of points (size, x coordinane, y coordinate) with links between them. Totally - millions of them.

I want to make project similar to google maps when I can rezise and move though points like map. I found something similar - http://neosigma.herokuapp.com/index.html
But I have next questions:

Can I load map by pieces via AJAX, as I have a script that gives me points that are visible in some place and some zoom. When user move map, I add more points. When user zoom out, I display more smaller points. I looked at documentation, but did not find answers.

If you know other solution, please, advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you first select a criteria you want to use to parse your data. Probably you don't want to query all the records in database at once.

1. I would define a starting point (e.g. nodes added by a certain user, a certain node's neighbors, etc.)
2. I'd query that data from mysql and convert it into Sigma readable format (preferably JSON).
3. Then you could feed that JSON to sigma and show the graph.

Once the user clicks on a node, you could load its neighborhood.

Here you have two options:

3.a Make a new request to the database and get the surrounding of that node. See how it's realized on http://www.textexture.com

3.b You could also load most of the graph for the exploration (maybe cached) and then show only local parts of it, like it's explained in this very nice tutorial made by Alexis who made Sigma: http://jcml.fr/~jacomyal/tuto-sigma/tuto-basics.html

You might also be interested to look into [Linkurious](http://linkurio.us/) - they have a solution you need for querying Neo4J databases but maybe they could help you with MySQL.